# How to use Route Task in Network analysis tools

Tags: arcgis-server, routing, network, network-analyst, arcgis-silverlight-api

I am using esri network analysis tool and I just want to draw the path between two clicked point on the map (by using route task)

I use the example code block in the following link 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#Routing 
which is included in the ESRI ARCGIS silverlight API sample page and I only change the route task and Dynamic layer URLs... In the end I always receive the error message as "Routing error: 'stops' parameter is invalid"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you using your own dataset? - the example above only works in North America.